# Irreducibility of $X^{4}-10X^{2}+1$ in $\mathbb{Q} [X]$...

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have to prove that $X^{4}-10X^{2}+1$  cannot be put as a product of two irreducible polynomials  in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and show that is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ the exercise also requires finding every root in  $\mathbb{Q}[X]$  and in $\mathbb{R}[X]$.

For the second and third part I tried to "complete squares"...

\begin{align*}
X^{4}-10X^{2}+1 & =\left(X^{2}-5\right)^{2}-24=\left(X^{2}-5\right)^{2}-\left(2\sqrt{6}\right)^{2}=\\
 & =\left(X^{2}-5+2\sqrt{6}\right)\left(X^{2}-5-2\sqrt{6}\right)
\end{align*}

The sum of irrationals is irrational and the square root of an irrational number is irrational so the polynomials above are irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, I don't know the proper proof for, after doing that, conclude that $X^{4}-10X^{2}+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Obviously the irrational square roots are $X=\pm\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}$ and $X=\pm\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}$ which are in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ and not in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Any ideas?

Comment: [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial))

Comment: You could also write $X = \pm \sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{3}$ as that covers all four roots: $$X = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} \\ X = -\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} \\ X = \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3} \\ X = -\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let$$r_1=\sqrt{5+2\sqrt6},\ r_2=-\sqrt{5+2\sqrt6},\ r_3=\sqrt{5-2\sqrt6},\text{ and }r_4=-\sqrt{5-2\sqrt6}.$$These numbers are the roots of $p(x)$. Since this polynomial has no rational roots, if it was reducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$, one of its factors would have to be $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$, $(x-r_1)(x-r_3)$, or $(x-r_1)(x-r_4)$. So, check that none of these polynomials belong to $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: Becomes even simpler if you use the fact that the roots are $r_{1,2,3,4}=\pm\sqrt2\pm\sqrt3$.

Comment: Nice! I missed that.